# Django ORM + async views + non-blocking IO

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

Is it fundamentally wrong to use an async view with thread_sensitive=False performing an Django ORM call?

For instance:

```
def call_to_a_3rd_party_API():
    something = requests.post(...)
    return something

@sync_to_async(thread_sensitive=False)
def do_something_to_a_product(request, id):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=id)
    result = call_to_a_3rd_party_API()
    product.some_value = result
    product.update()    ​
    ​return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

The goal here is that I am migrating some of my Django 2.2 views due to blocking IO behaviour (from calling 3rd party APIs) to Django 3.1 async views. In my tests, the only way I could turn the 3rd party API call in non-blocking is using thread_sensitive=False.

Reading the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/) it feels like we should never use thread_sensitive=False with Django ORM. So the alternative I guessed would be:

```
@sync_to_async(thread_sensitive=False)
def call_to_a_3rd_party_API():
    something = requests.post(...)
    return something

async def do_something_to_a_product(request, id):
    product = await sync_to_async(Product.objects.get, thread_sensitive=True)(Product, pk=id)
    result = await call_to_a_3rd_party_API()
    product.some_value = result
    await sync_to_async(product.save, thread_sensitive=True)
   ​return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

It feels like this way I can turn the call_to_a_3rd_party_API() into a non-blocking function, while keeping all the Django ORM in the main thread. But the code feels a lot more complex.

Could someone help me with this?

Extra question: I have two projects, one of them using wsgi and the other asgi. Does it make a difference regarding the issue above?

Comment: I have the exact same questions. Any luck on finding a definitive answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67735453/django-async-orm-sync-to-async-executor-swap-out-concurrent-futures-threadpoolex

Comment: Hey @jmunsch, i have been using the first example above in production for 2 months and still no problems (that I know of). But I havent had a definitive answer If using django ORM with thread sensitive False is fundamentally wrong. I have also moved a lot of blocking IO code whenever possible to celery tasks, since they run in an independent worker, and i have been using 8 gunicorn workers to minimize the impact when one worker is blocked. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the response. good to know.